# Pex Generated Tests Encoded UCS-2 Little Endian, Why, how to change?

Tags: pex

HI there

i noticed that when I generate a pex test solution the default encoding of the files is UCS-2 Little Endian, this is not really cool, because all the rest of the files are normally encoded with Windows ANSI 
(I m getting this info from Notepadd ++) and its confirmed by my CI breaking

Anyone knows
1) why is it using this encoding?
2) how to change it so by default it uses Windows ANSI like the rest of the files

NOTE:I know this is the issue because i saved the file with Windows Ansi Encoding and it all works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I probably shouldnt but I went and posted this same question on the pex forum 
[link to the question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/pex/thread/99f347e5-f5af-4521-8523-68b438d74b65/)

and this was an Answer from Peli ( he is heavily involved in the Pex project AFAIK)
Copy of the Answer

> 1) why is it using this encoding?
>
> There is no particular reason for this, besides that we decide to use this particular encoding. We will switch on Windows-1252 (ANSI) encoding in the future for source files. XML files will still be encoded as UTF-8.
>
> 2) how to change it so by default it uses Windows ANSI like the rest of the files
>
> Unfortunately, this is hard-coded in Pex and you cannot change this. The next release of Pex (0.93) will use ANSI.